# Get two numbers from a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an image url like so - `/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facade-510x340.jpg`. Is there a way I can get 510 (width) and 340 (height) from this url.

I need to use the information in this structure

```
<div class="item" data-w="510" data-h="340"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facade-510x340.jpg"></div>
<div class="item" data-w="200" data-h="340"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/waterfall-200x340.jpg"></div>
<div class="item" data-w="340" data-h="340"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facade-340x340.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Yes there is. There are even multiple ways. So... What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: I have tried looking for similar questions (here and Google), but couldn't find any and I have no clue about regex

Comment: Then you should grab a regular expression tutorial, and how to work with regular expressions in JavaScript. Or have a look at `String.prototype.split()`.

Comment: Perhaps use for example [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and use a regex pattern to using capturing groups to extract the values from the string ending on .jpg?

Comment: The with and the height seem to be in the data attributes as well. Perhaps use `document.querySelectorAll('div.item').forEach( i => console.log(i.dataset.w + "x"+ i.dataset.h));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should do the work, `.*-` captures everything until `-` so in your string it will match `/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facade-`, then `(\d+)` match a number with at least 1 digit into capture group, then `x` will capture letter `x` between numbers and then again capture `(\d+)` second number, then `match()` will return array of matches, first element is string on which was regex applied (your url), then other elements are that captured groups, in your case, these are width and height, respectively

```
var str = "/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facade-510x340.jpg"; 
var res = str.match(/.*-(\d+)x(\d+)/i);
if(res) {
    console.log(`Width: ${res[1]} Height: ${res[2]}`)
}
```